# Cancel user window sizing

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

After a user manually resizes a tkinter window, it no longer shrinks to fit.

What tkinter command would revert it back to the '*shrink to fit*' behavior?

Comment: It’s not clear what you are asking. Why do you want to cancel the resizing? Shouldn’t you be focused on making the app resize appropriately? Can you give us a minimal example of the problem you are asking about?

Comment: Im assuming you used, `grid()` and, i think the best way would be way is to disable the resizing option by `root.resizable(0,0)`. Maybe with code, we can understand better

Comment: There are several ways to achieve this and a general one seems hard to find. Please share with us your current situation

Comment: Sometimes I change which widgets are displayed by using `pack` and `pack_forget` as needed. If the user has placed the window into the manual size mode by manually resizing, the results are bad. The window is not resized automatically according to which widgets are active.

Comment: It's clear what he's asking only if you've run into this issue before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a hard time remembering how to this, as it has been so long.
In Tcl use:

```
wm geometry . {}
```

Can one of the python people edit the answer and translate this for tkinter, thanks.

@Atlas435 wrote this code for tkinter:

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()

def normal():
    root.geometry('')

b = tk.Button(root,text='shrink', command=normal)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Remember that the user resized his window for a reason.  Changing it back to some other size may not be what they want.